# How to include time delay in synthesized verilog?

Tags: verilog, timedelay

I am trying to write a synthesizable code in verilog, in which I require to include a time delay of few seconds. I have done the simulation using #delay, but this is not acceptable by synthesizer.

In the process of synthesizing a FSM, which change its states not based on some condition but after few seconds of time delay, I want the above time delay method. FSM has to switch states say from state_1 to state_2 after 4 seconds and state_2 to state_3 after 2 seconds and so on.

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz answered your question, but I'm just curious why do you need such a functionality?

Comment: I agree with @Vasiliy Zukanov, this is generally bad practice. If it is required to delay a repeating block used for refresh, then usually clock divider logic is used. Could you post more details? Maybe describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For switching the states after a time delay,I hope this code helps.

`current_state=state_1;

for(i=0;i<=timedelay*freq;i=i+1)

@posedge;

current_state=state_2;`

Answer (score 7):

If you know your clock frequency is x Hz, and you want to wait y seconds, then simply use a counter and wait until you reach the number x*y.

e.g. for a clock of 1kHz and a delay of 3 seconds this code will trigger do_something after the time delay.

```
`define CLOCK_FREQ 1000
`define TIME_DELAY 3

reg [31:0] count=0;

assign do_something = (count==`CLOCK_FREQ*`TIME_DELAY);

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   count <= count + 1'b1;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a clock of some frequency you can use a repeat statement. If you have a clock with a period of 1.25ns and you want to model a delay of 100ns. Then you need 1.25 * 100 = 125 cycles of your clock. You can do this then:

```
repeat (125) begin
    @(posedge clk);
end
// do stuff now
```

Comment: I checked [ug901 Vivado Synthesis Guide](https://docs.amd.com/v/u/2018.3-English/ug901-vivado-synthesis) and was surprised to find the statement "Vivado synthesis supports for and repeat statements. When using always blocks,
repetitive or bit slice structures can also be described using a for statement, or a repeat statement"